# How to integrate according to x?

Tags: probability, integration, variance, bayesian, means

I am new to bayesian and random variables. How do I find the mean and the variance of this distribution. The distribution is $$f(x|\gamma\ ^2) ∼ \gamma\ ^{(N-1)/2} e^{(-x^T\delta\ x )/2 \gamma\ ^2}  $$

I know that we need to integrate according to x to find the mean but how do we integrate $-x^T\delta\ x $. Any help would help.

Comment: xT is the transpose of the x

Comment: Do you know how to integrate generally? If yes, just try to write the formula and see where you can get. Then try to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: The thing is that I dont know how to integrate xTδ x

Comment: Are there any changes when there is a transpose?